# Extreme rope swinging - is this offered commercially at the location shown in 'World's Largest Rope Swing' video?

Tags: adventure, extreme-tourism, extreme-sports

I saw this video recently on YouTube titled '[World's Largest Rope Swing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4B36Lr0Unp4)' and this seems to have been shot with a custom rig set up just for the purposes of this video in Moab, Utah. What I want to know is whether any company offers this commercially at the same place, or failing which, elsewhere in the US.

To limit the scope, I specifically want to limit it to experiences as extreme as this (at least a 20 second swing, as [the behind-the-scenes video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_404545&feature=iv&src_vid=4B36Lr0Unp4&v=KkptQOPEWSg) states).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the largest swing in the world is the [Ben Nevis Swing](http://www.bungy.co.nz/the-nevis/the-nevis-swing) in Queenstown, New Zealand.

The stats:

Swing Stats:

- The World's Biggest Swing
- 300metre Arc
- 120m rope length (That's longer than a rugby field!)
- 160m above the river
- Swing options: Forwards, Backwards, Tandem, truck'n trailer, 69, back2back, Honeymoon & much more.
- Release options: Leave it up to the Ops Crew, let your mates take charge and use the remote or release yourself!

---

So if that doesn't meet your requirements, then you're probably going to have to rely on once-off custom swings like the one you mentioned.